# Automated Login Integration for Microsoft Teams Desktop Client

Tags: c#, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

My question is how can one programmatically automate the login process for the Microsoft Teams desktop client on Windows? Similar to Skype for Business, which provides DLLs for login automation, the goal is to create a Windows application that takes a user's username and password and then automatically logs in to the Microsoft Teams desktop client with these provided credentials. What tools, methods, or APIs can be used to achieve this integration with Microsoft Teams?

Any help would be great.

Thank you

Comment: There aren't any, because you're not supposed to.